# Facebook Not Updating Like Description

Tags: facebook, facebook-sharer

I am having trouble implementing the Like Description for one of my projects I am developing on my local machine. My problem was the I can only get the Title and Url to appear in the Like Description and it was missing the Image and the Text. I created a blank page with just a Like button and uploaded it onto a public server and noticed that I am unable to update the contents inside the Like Description.

For example, if you go to my test page below and click the Facebook Like button, you will see the Like Description description as 'Page description, expected to output'. However, if you view the page source, you will see that I have set the description with the Meta OG tag as `<meta property="og:description" content="This is a new page description"/>`. The current description tag is what I first used when I created this page.

So my question is why can I not update the Like Description? Does Facebook cache this somewhere on their server? If so, do you know how long it is cached for? In addition, will this work if I tested on my local?

http://www.sfu.ca/~jca41/stuph/test.html

```
<head>
    <meta property="og:url" content="http://www.sfu.ca/~jca41/stuph/test.html"/>
    <meta property="og:image" content="http://www.placehold.it/320x200/">
    <meta property="og:description" content="This is a new page description"/>  
    <meta property="og:title" content="Site title"/>
    <meta property="og:type" content="game"/>    
    <meta property="og:site_name" content="Site name"/> 
    <meta property="fb:admins" content="690014395"/>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="fb-root"></div>
    <script>(function(d, s, id) {
      var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
      if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
      js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
      js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1";
      fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

    <div class="fb-like" data-href="http://www.sfu.ca/~jca41/stuph/test.html" data-send="true" data-width="450" data-show-faces="false"></div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Facebook has a tool called Debugger, this tool fetches the latest content, and also updates it cache with the latest content: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug

This should help.

Comment: How about if I am testing on my local? Will this tool help me?

Comment: I tried to like your page, and I got the right description ;)
« This is a new page description »